# How bright a light should be to be considered in part of atomic spectrum？

Tags: spectroscopy

I've been doing atomic spectrum experience, and besides the major peaks, there are many little bumps shows up. I looked up for an official one, found that they only shows the major peaks on the spectrum. But I think the bumps should also be a part of the spectrum? Or how did them define it then?

Comment: How many "bumps" do you need listed? [NIST Atomic Spectra Database Lines Form](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675629/how-bright-a-light-should-be-to-be-considered-in-part-of-atomic-spectrum)

Comment: @Farcher I don't know either, how pro guys did it?

Comment: The NIST tables of **strong** emission lines of elements are a very good start, but they are **only the tip of the iceberg**. For example, when I was assigning neon emission lines, I used the neon **strong** lines table here: https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/neontable2.htm. But my spectra had more lines than in that table. So I found a much more comprehensive paper, by scientists at NIST, and that let me assign more lines. Impurities are a fact of life, but it is unwise to jump too quickly to assuming impurities in spectra. Same for measurement noise. I will upvote, BTW.

Comment: Just upvoted, as promised! And this reference seems to be the best available for neon: E.B. Saloman, Craig J. Sansonetti, Wavelengths, Energy Level Classifications, and Energy Levels for the Spectrum of Neutral Neon, J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data, Vol. 33, No. 4, 2004. It is freely available on the web. For other elements, e.g., argon or uranium, etc., you basically have to do a good search. Best of success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official lists always relate to a certain element. This may be the main element in your experiment (producing the major peaks), but there will always be small contaminations by other elements, which show up as smaller 'bumps'. You would need to have a look at different tables to identify these.

Comment: but I'm thinking these bumps are from the same samples, since there are other energy levels in addition to the main ones anyway?

Comment: If you can't find the locations of the bumps listed for the spectrum of the element you are examining, it is highly likely that these are due to contamination by other elements.